# Is there a Microsoft Visual C++ equivalent to register_printf_function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printf

I'm trying to register a custom format specifier for a type in c++. I've found [register_printf_function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html) for the GNU ecosystem, but cannot find an equivalent for the Microsoft ecosystem. Does one exist?

edit: I should mention that I cannot use iostream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but since you're using C++ you can do something similar with `operator<<` and `std::cout`.

Comment: 'No' looks like the correct answer. Proving a negative is always a challenge, but I haven't been able to find anything. This, btw, is the first good reason I've seen to use iostreams instead of printf!

Answer (score 0):

Before exploring ways of customizing `printf` function while programming in Visual C++, take some time thinking about why you would use C-style `printf` at first place.

Since you're programming in C++, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects instead of C-style strings and for custom and more complex string formatting, use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Comment: std::string and std::stringstream perform dynamic allocation, and I am working in a domain that largely forbids dynamic allocation. iostream is also not available.

Comment: @DanO: "domain that forbids dynamic allocation"? ...I don't know what you mean with it, but in case you're working within specific environment with strict and unreasonable constraints, you should describe it in your question.

Comment: There are lots of applications that cannot use dynamic allocation, consider these specs: http://www.appinf.com/download/SafetyCriticalC++Presentation.pdf Anyway, my question was quite specific. You don't have to provide an answer if you don't have one.

Comment: @DanO: *"You don't have to provide an answer if you don't have one"* ~> I was just trying to help you... but I didn't expect that your response will be downvote and an arrogant comment of this kind. You could have rather edited your question to make it describe the problem properly.

Comment: FYI I didn't downvote you, and I don't think my comment was 'arrogant', but if it came off that way my apologies. It looks like this is a feature is not available in MS land so I'm SOL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [freopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for output redirection.

Comment: My question doesn't have anything to do with output redirection! That's all these are for, isn't it?